# Hierarchical TreeList View WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, treeview, treelistview

Basically I need to implement a control like this one in WPF, preferably with MVVM support:

[image: treelistview]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-01-77-44-83/CTP_5F00_Metrics_5F00_Window.png))</sub>

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this using **TreeView** with some styles for TreeViewItem :

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeViewItem Header="Employee1">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Jesper"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Aaberg"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="12345"/>
  </TreeViewItem>    
</TreeView>
```

or you can take a look at Tekerik controls : [http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx](http://Telerik)

which as controls as you wish but sure with a price :)